# Java Math.pow((1/(1+1),1) not evaluating correctly

Tags: java

I was trying experimenting with Java a little, and this problem came up:

```
public class TestRandom {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Math.pow((1/(1+1)),1));
    }
}
```

evaluated to `0.0`, which was most likely originally NaN.

Is there something wrong with me or is there a real explanation?

Comment: Integer division, and why are you raising `0.5` to the first anyway? Just write `0.5`.

Comment: Elliot, this is a large oversimplification of the real thing.

Answer (score 11):

You've got an integer division in there.  `1/2` is `0`, not `0.5`.

You could try changing the expression to `Math.pow((1.0/(1+1)),1)` to force this to be a floating-point division.

**Edit**

Division in Java has been designed in the same way as it was in C and C++, which came before Java.  When you do division with two expressions of type `int`, you get a result of type `int`.  This was a choice that the language designers made, for better or worse, and we're stuck with it now.  But basically it means that any fractional result from a division gets rounded downwards (strictly speaking, towards zero).  In this case, `1/2` gets rounded to `0`.

The same kind of thing happens with `long`.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) says

> Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the quotient produced for operands n and d that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is an integer value q whose magnitude is as large as possible while satisfying |d · q| ≤ |n|. Moreover, q is positive when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have the same sign, but q is negative when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have opposite signs.
>
> There is one special case that does not satisfy this rule: if the dividend is the negative integer of largest possible magnitude for its type, and the divisor is -1, then integer overflow occurs and the result is equal to the dividend. Despite the overflow, no exception is thrown in this case. On the other hand, if the value of the divisor in an integer division is 0, then an ArithmeticException is thrown.

Comment: I know you just posted, but prehaps, you can explain why his code produces 0? To any new developer, it wouldn't make sense why Java converts 1/2 to an integer.

Comment: @WaffleStealer654 Happy now?  I don't know what else I can say about it.

Comment: Lol. Yes. I try to encourage people to put in the "why". Instead of just giving code.

Comment: Sure.  But variations on this question have been asked over and over.  Maybe I should have just flagged it as "duplicate" instead of answering it.